# How we can find an element from [AnyObject] type array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, anyobject

I have [AnyObject] array

```
var updatedPos = [AnyObject]()
```

I am setting data in that according to my requirement like!

```
let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
para.setValue(posId, forKey: "id")
para.setValue(posName, forKey: "job")
let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(para, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
self.updatedPos.append(jsonString)
```

Now in my code i have some requirement to remove the object from this array where **id** getting matched according to requirement **Here is the code which i am trying to implement**

```
for var i = 0; i < updatedPos.count; i++
        {
            let posItem = updatedPos[i]
            print("Id=\(posItem)")
            let pId = posItem["id"] as? String
            print("secRId=\(pId)")
            
            if removeId! == pId!
            {
                updatedPos.removeAtIndex(i)
            }
        }
```

Here `print("Id=\(posItem)")` give me output as`Id={"id":"51","job":"Programmer"}` but here i am not able to access **id** from this object. here `print("secRId=\(pId)")` give me **nil**

Comment: Why do you save the JSON string rather than the collection type (dictionary)?

Comment: @vadian that is my requirement i just need `id` from this object

Comment: The question is why do you save a **string** and not a **dictionary**?

Answer (score 1):

- First of all use native Swift collection types.
- Second of all use types as specific as possible.

For example your `[AnyObject]` array can be also declared as an array of dictionaries `[[String:AnyObject]]`

```
var updatedPos = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

Now create the dictionaries and add them to the array (in your example the dictionary is actually `[String:String]` but I keep the `AnyObject` values).

```
let para1 : [String:AnyObject] = ["id" : "51", "job" : "Programmer"]
let para2 : [String:AnyObject] = ["id" : "12", "job" : "Designer"]
updatedPos.append(para1)
updatedPos.append(para2)
```

If you want to remove an item by `id` use the filter function

```
let removeId = "12"
updatedPos = updatedPos.filter { $0["id"] as? String != removeId  }
```

or alternatively

```
if let indexToDelete = updatedPos.indexOf{ $0["id"] as? String == removeId} {
   updatedPos.removeAtIndex(indexToDelete)
}
```

The JSON serialization is not needed for the code you provided.

PS: Never write `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` unless you know exactly what it's doing.

Comment: It may be best solution i didn't try that i will try it later, i just need a simple suggestion, can we get an item from   `Id={"id":"51","job":"Programmer"}`. Forgot else why i am converting this into Json string. I really will be very thank full to you if you can provide me an solution with my code

Comment: Once again, according to your code `jsonString` is a literal **String**, there is no item. If you don't need the JSON serialization, edit your question and remove the irrelevant code.

Comment: but when i am sending data to the API then i need this data into JSON Object. That's why i have created this thing.

Comment: The fact is your code does not work, and providing a solution for your code (filtering literal strings) is much more complicated than using the dictionary version.

Comment: Ok let me try with your solution i have to do lots'of change for that i am trying to and let you know

Comment: i did try this answer if i try this then it's giving me an 2D array, which is not ful fill the requirement, if i would try this solution in my code then i need to create new api for that so i don't want to go for it, i will be verry happy if you could provide a solution with same `Id={"id":"51","job":"Programmer"}` object to find the array,

Answer (score 0):

After some little bit stuffs I have found the very easy and best solution for my question. And I want to do special thanks to @vadian. Because he teach me new thing here. Hey Thank you very much @vadian

Finally the answer is I had covert `posItem` in `json Format` for finding the `id` from `Id={"id":"51","job":"Programmer"}` this string

And the way is

```
let data = posItem.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
   do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
           let id = dict["id"]
           if removeId! == id! as! String
             {
               updatedLoc.removeAtIndex(i)
             }        
          }
       }
     catch {
        print(error)
     }
```